# Implementing Apollo Client for Subscriptions in Next.js

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to implement Subscriptions from Apollo Client in my next.js application. I have used @graphql-codegen/cli to implement queries and mutations, so I just want to use Apollo for Subscriptions.

Here is my code:

```
import "@/styles/globals.scss";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  split,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { GraphQLWsLink } from "@apollo/client/link/subscriptions";
import { createClient } from "graphql-ws";
import { getMainDefinition } from "@apollo/client/utilities";

const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT as string,
  })
);

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT as string,
});

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnMount: true,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: WebSocket implementation missing; on Node you can `import WebSocket from 'ws';` and pass `webSocketImpl: WebSocket` to `createClient`
    at createClient (file:///E:/work/Slayr/slayr-web/node_modules/graphql-ws/lib/client.mjs:73:15)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.tsx:28:153) {
  page: '/'
```

I tried importing WebSocket from 'ws' and passing it to createClient but then I was getting this error instead

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid WebSocket implementation provided
```